# get_term_link throws WP_ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, taxonomy

I am retrieving the term link using get_term_link and echoing it in a href (link).

It works on the website but when I crawl the website it `throws the status code 500`.
I have discovered this when it appeared in the php_errors.log on the server.

> Error: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not
>   be converted to string in ..etc/etc/

```
$get_term = get_term_by('slug', 'term', 'taxonomy');
$link = get_term_link($get_term->term_id, 'taxonomy');
```

How can I avoid this crawling issue? Your feedback is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: put all code into your question. we can't guess why is the error appears

Answer (score 1):

Please check this url.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/#return

```
(string|WP_Error) HTML link to taxonomy term archive on success, WP_Error if term does not exist.
```

get_term_link() function returns (string|WP_Error).

Because you provided a bit code. Here are my possible solutions.

- get_term_link() first parameter not only accepts term id but also term object. 
  so I suggest to change 
  this

  ```
  $link = get_term_link($get_term->term_id, 'taxonomy');
  ```

  to

  ```
  $link = get_term_link($get_term, 'taxonomy');
  ```
- Check this function returns exact value.

  ```
  $get_term = get_term_by('slug', 'term', 'taxonomy');
  ```

Hope these help.

Thanks